# Is there an application like screen but for GUI applications?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm running few projects at the moment, I'd like to switch between them without closing and reopening all applications. Is there a way to do so with some screen-like application? Only way till now is switching logged in users, but I'd like to avoid this. We can assume linux machine, no memory limit.

Comment: I think it's called "X" :-)

Comment: I believe "switching" actually refers to "backgrounding" -- allowing the application to run independent of the X server.

Comment: This is some option, I tried is some years before and forget about it now :) But same problem as with switching users occur: one screen at a time, there is screen A or screen B and no out-of-screen applications (IM, e-mail, browser etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[xpra](http://xpra.org/) claims to be such a thing.  I've never used it.

(I've heard of another tool like that, but I don't remember the name.)

Comment: Description looks like it's what i want, I'll check it out.

Comment: You should probably try [this fork](http://xpra.org/) which is more up to date. The other tool you have heard of was probably NX (NX provides both libraries which can be used by many solutions including open source servers, and a proprietary server). If you want to try that too, I would recommend [winswitch](http://winswitch.org/)

Comment: @totaam: I updated the link. (The old and defunct one was [here](https://github.com/njsmith/partiwm).)

Answer (score 3):

I've normally used a vnc application for this purpose. It's not ideal, but it works for me.

You basically just connect to the vnc every time and make sure you don't log it off...